# Strange behavior of Array.Clone()

Tags: c#

I have a static array like below

```
static byte[] myArray = {0x01,0x02};
```

I read that [Array.clone does shallow copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx).Then i execute the below codes.

```
byte[] myArray2 = myArray.Clone() as byte[];
myArray2[0] = 0x05;
```

But now Each myArray2[0] and myArray[0] contains different values.So I think Array.Clone() is performing a deep copy .Can you explain why?

Comment: Hi, shallow or deep copy have no meaning in the context of a simple value type like byte or int. Since the array contains the value and not the reference, once you clone it and you change the value in any of them, such change is not propagated to the other array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`byte` is a primitive type, not a reference. Thus there is no difference between shallow and deep copy in this case.

Try using an array of a mutable object type, and you will notice the difference.

#### Update

> but byte[] is a reference type right?

An array of a primitive type is deep down most probably represented by a contiguous block of memory, physically (*by value*) containing the elements. Whereas an array of an object type is a contiguous block of memory, containing only *references* to the actual elements (or `null`s). Thus when you copy the array, in the first case you get a new array containing *copies* of the elements of the original. So after that, modifying an element in either of the arrays won't change the contents of the other array. Whereas in the second case you get a new array containing copies of the *references* in the original, **still pointing to the same objects referred to by the original array elements**. So if you modify any of the elements in either of the array, the change will be visible in the other array too.

Comment: Try it with a mutable reference type, i.e.: `Person[]` and you will see.

Comment: @Vaysage: Clone is copying the contents of the array, not the array itself.  The contents of the array are value types.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx.

Comment: @Vaysage but Clone operates on the elements of the array, and they are not reference types in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A shallow copy means it copies the immediate values.  If those values are pointers (reference types like objects in C#), then the pointers are copied over, and the values they point to (the state of the object) is not copied.

If the immediate values are primitives (ie: the value itself resides in the array, it's not *referenced*) then those values are copied.  Hence the behavior is exactly as expected.

If you want to see the difference in your case, define an array of `Object`s.

Comment: `Byte` is not a boxed byte. This is C#, not Java.

Comment: @LukeH Right you are.  The perils of switching back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Person person = new Person { Name = "Vaysage" };

Person[] persons1 = new Person[] { person  };

Person[] persons2 = (Person[])persons1.Clone();

persons2[0].Name = ".NET Junkie";

Assert.AreEqual(persons1[0].Name, ".NET Junkie");
```

The arrays are shallowly copied. This means that just references to the `Person` objects are copied and not the whole objects. Both arrays reference the same person object and thus the name of the person in the first array is changed as well.

Comment: Thanks .Now i understood that `Array.Clone` works on members of array .Previously i believed that it works on Array,thats why i asked this question.